# event.altKey is not returning anything

Tags: javascript, angular

I'am trying to show / hide a div if the Alt button is pressed. I'm listening to a keypress and using `event.altKey` to determine if alt/option was pressed. But this wasn't working. So I logged the event.

```
@HostListener( 'document:keypress', [ '$event' ])
handleKeyboardEvent( event: KeyboardEvent ) {
    console.log( event.altKey );
}
```

In the above code if I pressed any number, alphabet or symbol it will print 'false' as expected. But when I press Alt, Ctrl, Shift, Tab nothing happens. It doesn't print true or false.

I also tried printing the keycode. It prints for everything but 'Alt, Ctrl, Shift, Tab'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you try  event.which || event.keyCode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keypress doesn't detect some keys, and alt must be one of those keys. I would try using a different event called `onkeydown`. It can detect more keys. Here's more info on the keydown event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown

Comment: keypress also does fire repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

you can the following function for `alt` key function :

```
function isKeyPressed(event) {
    if (event.altKey) {
        console.log("The ALT key was pressed!");
    } else {
        console.log("The ALT key was NOT pressed!");
    }
}
```

and in your html use `onkeydown="isKeyPressed(event)"` as tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try `host property` within `@Component` decorator.

```
@Component({
  ...
  host: {
    '(document:keypress)': 'handleKeyboardEvent($event)'
  }
})
export class AppComponent {
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Angular recommend using @HostListener decorator over host property 
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-03